# Flutter Acessibilidade - O rótulo deste item pode não ser lido por leitores de tela. - Tela/VIew

Tags: android, flutter, acessibilidade

Olá! Estou com uma dúvida de acessibilidade com flutter para android. Alguém pode me dar uma mãozinha? Estou tentando subir um app na loja (android) mas estou recebendo relatórios de erro de acessibilidade. Sâo uns 700 erros iguais, dizendo:

**O rótulo deste item pode não ser lido por leitores de tela.**

O item marcado é a tela inteira.

[O rótulo deste item pode não ser lido por leitores de tela.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUhqQ.png)

Eu baixei um Scaner de Acessibilidade e deu exatamente a mesma coisa. No código eu tentei colocar "Semantics" com "label" em tudo quanto é canto, mas o erro persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar opções de acessibilidade para leitores de tela, você pode seguir a [documentação oficial do Flutter sobre acessibilidade](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/accessibility#screen-readers).

Para o problema em questão (mensagem *"O rótulo deste item pode não ser lido por leitores de tela."*), você pode resolver adicionando a seguinte linha de código antes da função runApp do Flutter:

```
RendererBinding.instance.setSemanticsEnabled(true);
```

Meus apps publicados na Play Store sempre deram o mesmo erro/aviso, e isso resolveu.

Comment: Caso seu app contenha Widgets não padrão do Flutter (algum que você mesmo criou com base em outros Widgets), você pode usar o [Semantic Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Semantics-class.html) para definir manualmente a descrição do Widget (confirme está na documentação).

Answer (score -3):

For Flutter 3.10.0 and further

```
SemanticsBinding.instance.ensureSemantics();
```